# Apache Kylin stuck on 'Convert Cuboid Data to HFile'

Tags: cube, kylin, warehouse

I installed the following stack on my lab setup:

- Hadoop 2.7.1
- Hive 1.2.2
- HBase 1.7.1
- Kylin 3.1.2

I now try to build a cube from the sample dataset provided by Kylin itself, and the process gets stuck at 78.26% "Convert Cuboid Data to HFile". The logs do not show any error and it fails after a few hours, probably because of a timeout.

Did anyone of you encounter that problem and managed to solve it?

Comment: I find the lack of entries in the log peculiar: are you sure you're looking at the right place in the logs? Do you see the timeouts in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, this behaviour is described:

> On some Hadoop release, you may encounter the following error in the
> “Convert Cuboid Data to HFile”:
>
> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
> Could not create  interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceFactory 
> Is the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath?
> ```

The prescribed solution is to add `hbase-hadoop2-compat-*.jar` and `hbase-hadoop-compat-*.jar` into $KYLIN_HOME/spark/jars (the two jar files can be found in HBase’s lib folder); If you already make the Spark assembly jar and uploaded to HDFS, you may need to re-package that and re-upload to HDFS.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer as the lack of information about Kylin drives me crazy. Does the solution you proposed work if Spark isn't used? Or do I have to enable Spark to be able to build cubes as Kylin states that it is optional

Comment: I would install Spark. I don't think Kylin has reached maturity and it may be that there are dependencies, that are not properly explained / documented...